# Number of affine points on an elliptic curve

Tags: elliptic-curves

I'm given an elliptic curve $y^2=x^3+ax+b \in \mathbb{Z}_p[x]$ (with numbers $a,b,p$ not greater than $10^6$).

I would like to find, using the naive approach, the number of affine points on the curve without the point at infinity .

My approach is to go through all $x\in\mathbb{Z}_p$ and check which of them have residue (stored in **counter**. Since each $x$ has either two or zero residues, I multiply the number of $x$ with residues times 2.

To return the number of affine points, the following method is used:

```
if isSingular(a,b,p):
    return counter*2+2
return counter*2+1
```

It seems to work for some cases, but not for others. Is there something special we have to consider for singular curves, and why?

Comment: 'Since each $x$ has either two or zero residues'; actually, if $x^3 + ax + b = 0 \pmod p$, it has only one residue (and hence only one point corresponding to that $x$ coordinate).

Comment: I think the word "residue" does not mean what you think it means...

Comment: The quadratic residue is if there exists a value $y$, such that $y^2=x (mod p)$?

Comment: You can use Schoof's algorithm to count the number of affine points on the elliptic curve.

Comment: @Venkatesh, Schoof's algorithm is too complex and is useful when primes have several hundred digits. My problem is more of a theoretical nature (i.e. I want to understand how to count them manually).

Comment: @Artem Elliptic curves are *by definition* non-singular. Does poncho's comment explain your observations?

Comment: I tried it now and it helped!

Comment: @kelalaka I have not posted the solution

Comment: @kelalaka, you are right, sorry for the typo :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final code that worked for is shown below (published [here](https://github.com/artemlos/PythonCrypto/blob/master/ecc.py))

```
# Returns number of affine points on the elliptic curve (wihout point at inf).
def countResidues(a, b, p):

    counter  = 0
    for x in range(0,p):

        # the curve in 
        y2 = (x**3+a*x+b) % p

        # if x^3+ax+b = 0 (mod p), then there exists one point only.
        # i.e. the point is still on the curve even if there is no residue.
        if y2 == 0:
            counter += 1
            continue

        # if quadratic residues exists, two points are on the curve
        # i.e. the solutions to y^2 = x^3+ax+b (mod p)
        if isQuadRes(y2, p):
            counter +=2

    return counter


# Check if a curve is singular by checking that 4a^3+27b^2 = 0
# See p. 255 in course lit.
def isSingular(a, b, p):
    return ( -(4*a*a*a % p)-(27*b*b % p)) % p == 0


# Determines if there exists an x such that x^2=a (mod p), in other words,
# it will return true if the quadratic residue exists.
# Based on Euler's criterion, see course lit p. 180.
def isQuadRes(a,p):
    return squareAndMultiply(a,((p-1)//2), p) == 1

# Convert integer to binary representation
def intToBin(number):
    return '{:b}'.format(number)

# Computes number mod base
def mod(number, base):
    return number - base * (number//base)

# Calculate 'x^c mod n' using square-and-multiply algorithm.
def squareAndMultiply(x,c,n):

    # get the binary representation of c, the exponent.
    b = intToBin(c) 

    z = 1

    # the main algorithm, adjusted from p. 177 from course lit.
    for i in range(len(b)):
        z = mod(z*z, n)

        if b[i] == '1':
            z = mod(z*x, n)
    return z
```

Course lit refers to [https://www.amazon.com/Cryptography-Practice-Discrete-Mathematics-Applications/dp/1584885084](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1584885084)